# Get reference to a serialised List<GameObject> in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I need to get a reference to my List in a particular class that's marked as serializable.

From what I've researched I would need to make a separate class to act as a container, then serialize a List of that class. However this would prove very cumbersome in my particular solution.

**Can I serialize a List of gameObjects then access and mutate those values through the UnityEditor API?**

**Pseudocode**

```
var listOfGameObjects = serializedObject.FindProperty("listofgameobjects");//something like this 

//I'd do some logic to mutate some sub properties/objects contained in a particular GameObject

//then dirty the attribute so Unity updates the new values I input through the GUI
serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();

but it gets a reference to the List of gameObjects
```

**Context**
I have a List holding slides for a popup. In my GUI it loops through all of the "slides"and allows me to edit certain components that are children of a given slide GameObject's(such as Text, and Image)

**EDIT:**

I need to reference the GameObjects, then mutate them through those references, then mark them dirty and save them in the Editor

I have written the following script to automatically save dirty edits in the Editor for a given amount of time..

```
public static class SaveDirtyEdits//container to hold our coroutine, static because we only want one to be running
{
    public static System.Collections.IEnumerator UpdateDirtyGUIChanges(float timeTillSave)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeTillSave);
        //the items that are marked dirty are done automatically in the GUI scripts written for the button manager
        UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
    }
}

public class LeidosAlwaysRunInEditor : Editor
{
    public void Update()
    {
        SaveDirtyEdits.UpdateDirtyGUIChanges(120f);//start a coroutine to save dirty edits (every x amount of input seconds)
        MoveNextTarget();//not sure what this does but you need it to update the changes we are applying with our coroutine 
    }
}
```

How to I mark these Game-object References as dirty?

Comment: `Can I serialize a List of gameObjects then access and mutate those values through the UnityEditor API?` Probably not. The UnityEditor namespace and all classes that derive from there are not compiled into the build executable. You should explain what you are trying to do rather than how you're doing it.

Comment: @Draco18s Ive given a brief description of what I'm doing, if you need additional information don't hesitate to say what you require

Comment: You don't need to work with `SerializedObject/SerializedProperty`, just mutate the objects then mark the root object as dirty, finally call `AssetDatabase.SaveAssets` or `Ctrl+S` to save the changes.

Comment: @shingo Could you share some psuedo code in an answer or in here? It would allow me to work it out easier. Thanks a ton